# How can I make 2 viewports in Blender python have the same orientation?

Tags: python, 3d-view

I have this code:

```
def main(context):
    for area in context.screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            r3d = area.spaces.active.region_3d 
            view_matrix = r3d.view_matrix
```

How can I change the view_matrix so that it becomes something with my values? I did `view_matrix[0][0] = some_value` etc... but it doesn't change values (and it doesn't give me errors).

So lets say I have 2 screens of `3D_VIEW` with different orientations. How can I make them have the same orientation? (that's what i'm trying to do)

Comment: Would you accept placing a camera at this spot and aligning both views to this camera?

Comment: Yes.Could you please elaborate more about that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the values works for me. The below script changes all 3D views to the first one (by internal order). This does not work in all cases but in most.

```
C = bpy.context
viewports_3D = []
for area in C.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        viewports_3D.append(area)

attributes=['view_matrix', 'view_distance', 'view_perspective', 
            'use_box_clip', 'use_clip_planes', 'is_perspective',
            'show_sync_view', 'clip_planes']
ref_viewport = viewports_3D[0].spaces.active.region_3d

for viewport_3D in viewports_3D:
    for attribute in attributes:
        setattr(viewport_3D.spaces.active.region_3d, attribute, getattr(ref_viewport, attribute))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help.I tried it and it gives me:"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Text", line 15, in <module>
AttributeError: 'RegionView3D' object has no attribute 'clip_planes'
Error: Python script fail, look in the console for now...So i removed this and 'use_clip_planes'.It worked fantasticly!!!Could you also explain me the last 3 lines of code(those with 2 for)?What exactly do you do with setattr()?

Comment: @kostas The outer loop is because all 3D viewports should be affected, the inner loop because all attributes of the reference viewport should be copied to each viewport. `getattr` and `setattr` allow to access attributes of python objects by their string name. The last two lines could be replaced by `viewport_3D.spaces.active.region_3d.view_matrix = ref_viewport.view_matrix`, `viewport_3D.spaces.active.region_3d.view_distance = ref_viewport.view_distance` and so on for all other attributes. Instead I create a list of attribute names and loop over all of them for more compact code.

Comment: @kostas The only reason I can imagine why `clip_planes` won't work is a different Blender version. I have used 2.79.