# viewport synchronization

Tags: python, scripting, 3d-view

is there a convenient tip, or method from within the python console, to echo Ctrl+MMB / Shift+MMB events to several viewports simultaneously. My concern is to pan and zoom in an ortho-top 3d view and obtain the same navigation effect in a distinct Camera view.

I read this [post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90868/how-can-i-make-2-viewports-in-blender-python-have-the-same-orientation), but it does not do the job as it turns back my camera view to 3d persp or ortho view (indeed the same as the parent viewport). Any clue is welcome !

Thanks,
V.